# Printing objects work but drawing it won't?

Tags: java, graphics

So every time I try to draw my list of objects it won't draw it. I have draw methods under my class and seems like everything works since the while loop under `update()` method works like it should. If that iterates through the list and prints out correctly how can I implement that to read the same list under paintComponent? It seems as if when I try it gives me a null pointer exception which means it must be empty.

update:

```
public void update(IObservable o, Object arg){
    gwp = (GameWorldProxy) o;
    gameObjects = gwp.getCollection().getIterator();
    while(gameObjects.hasNext()){
        GameObject gameObj = (GameObject) gameObjects.getNext();
        System.out.println(gameObj);
    }
    this.repaint();
}
```

paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    while(gameObjects.hasNext()){
        GameObject gameObj = (GameObject) gameObjects.getNext();
        gameObj.draw(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check your stacktrace, I'm guessing gameObjects is null for some reason

Comment: my stack trace points right to where the while loop starts under paintComponent

Comment: Check if gameObjects is null, and if so, exit the method without drawing.

Comment: `gameObjects` may be `null` because `update` has't been called yet...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I figured it out but it seems that you might be right, I need to call it since the first one is always null then when I add a new object it works fine.